# After upgrade android version getting "Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel"

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

before android update 3.4 my application run perfectly but after upgrade android my application getting merging error:

```
"Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel"

android update 3.4
upgrade gradle 5.1.1 
upgrade sdk

Error:
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.package-info found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelUtils found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$ParcelException found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$FieldBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$InputBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
    Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelize found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

------------------DEPENDENCY------------

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha4'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    //crop image library...
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    //ButterKnife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    //Google play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    //gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    // Room
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    //cardview & recyclerview
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //picasoo
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.3'
    //firebase-cloud massaging..
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: can we see your `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file. you probably have both `androidx` libraries and `com.android.support` libraries in conflict with each other

Comment: sure @user3170251,

Comment: i update dependencies here now you can see my project dependency

Answer (score 16):

You have `androidx` libraries (probably in one of the used libraries) conflicting with the `support` libraries.

Add these lines into your `gradle.properties` file: (It's in the root directory of your project)

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

The Jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages instead.

Comment: this didn't solve my problem. Any other alternative?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: i too have this problem .I have just upgrading gradle version from 2.3 to 3.4.1 .I don't have use or integrate androidx in my application.any one have another solution?

Comment: @civanimahida Are you sure, you are not using any third party library like firebase which is using androidx?

Comment: thank you I used firebase and when I delete it, I didn't get duplicate error anymore

Comment: For me issue was solved after adding both lines, previously I was added only one line as useAndroidX I think that was causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

First Select **Refractor** from top bar then from that select **refract** **to** **androidx** so it will create a **zip file** for you as a back up.

After that it will automatically be fine and fixes all kind of bugs and errors that are stopping the phone app from running

*That's it!! You did it*

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines in your gradle.Proparties

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).