# android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle() and import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat; problems

Tags: android-studio, androidx, support-v4

Hi i have problems when i try to update ( migration to andoridx, i added some pictures at the end of this post) my app, especialy in this code:

`.setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(service.getMediaSession().getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1)
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setCancelButtonIntent(stopAction));`

but when i try to update this:`import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;`

i have this in my build.grade:`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` the problem comes when i try to use androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0
because the error says:

error: cannot find symbol class NotificationCompat and in the implement section, this go in grey color`import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;` 
and says
cannot resolve symbol NotificationCompat

I dont know how to solve this, if anyone knows, please tell me. Thanks for your time

[more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osb9A.jpg)

[More details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au240.png)

Answer (score 4):

- first of all: it's a **migration problem to androidX**
- don't make it manually
- androidstudio (3.5.1) has a migrate to androidX function:

  - right-click on **root-folder** of your project->**Refactor**->**Migrate to AndroidX**
  - more detailed instruction here: [After upgrade android version getting "Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810694/after-upgrade-android-version-getting-duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-in)